# Cross-os simple web-browser for Facebook authenticating

Tags: java, facebook, authentication, browser

I'm currently trying to allow users to login with their Facebook account in my Java application. However, that requires a browser to show the Facebook-authenticate web-page.

I'm now looking for a "browser"-project which:

- is **cross-os**
- Supports **single frames** (i.e show a page at that url, no forward/back/refresh buttons)
- Supports relatively new web-standards (which Facebook uses)
- Preferably **lightweight**

I'm trying to avoid Eclipse SWT due to all the hassle it requires to get cross-os to be working. This is a relatively small project which I'd like to keep simple. A swing-based browser isn't an alternative either due to its lack of support for newer web-standards.

**Is there any project which does what I'm looking for**? Is there an alternative way of doing this, without a browser, that is?

Comment: Mozilla had a thing called “Prism” once, for stand-alone browser-based applications. Although that has been discontinued now, there project pages lists two alternatives, that might be worth a look: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your reply! Neither Chromeless or WebRunner seems to be able to be downloaded..

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t look further – it seems those have been discontinued now as well. Would a “normal” browser, started in “kiosk” mode, maybe be able to solve your problem?

Comment: @CBroe Absolutely! As long as I have programmatic access to the browser (preferably location-listener events that fire upon url-change), and the browser itself supports the basics of Facebook; it'd be perfect. Preferably, it'd only contain the page itself; without adress-bar/back-forward-buttons; that's not required, however.

Comment: @CBroe Do you know such a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried any of the following controls:

- [WebView in JavaFX 2.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)
- [Lobo Browser](http://lobobrowser.org/browser/api-info.jsp)
- [SWT Browser Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html)
- [WebRenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com/products/swing/developer/examples.php) (paid)
- [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/store/jxbrowser/) (paid)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! WebView doesn't seem to offer any functionality to subscribe to location/url changes? Other then that it's perfect. SWT would be perfect if it wasn't for the fact that it adds quite a bit hassle to get it working cross-os. Lobo Browser seems to be dead and doesn't support Java 7 at all..

Comment: Their was one component I didn't mention because it isn't free. But it seems to satisfy all your needs and has a 30 day trail to see if it really can do what you need. Added it to the list.

Comment: I decided to go with JavaFX; I'll update your answer later to share a code snipped of how I did it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Lobo Browser](http://lobobrowser.org/browser/api-info.jsp) with success previously. What you want to do is to add a NavigationAdapter to your BrowserPanel and then check if NavigationEvent url is set to

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for a successful authorization.

For more information on the last part check out corresponding [Facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 2):

you can try javaFX2.0, if you are using jdk1.7 it works on Windows, Linux and Mac.
you can embedd the browser in swing panel and show/hide the back/refresh/forward/address bars.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm

instead of creating your own way, i would suggest that you should use the OAuth API, and see if the user's login was successful or not.
and if you application store only user's basic info which you can fetch with the help of OAuth.
in this case you don't need to worry about handling the user password.